# (Windows 11) Command Prompt doesn't recognize that Python (3.10.6) is installed?

Tags: python, cmd

So I installed Python 3.10.6. Apparently, if you type "python" into Command Prompt, it'll return your Python application specs if you have it installed, and return `Python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` if you don't. However, I'm getting redirected to the Microsoft store (which I presume means that Command Prompt thinks I don't have Python installed), even though I do have Python installed.

Right now, Python is in `C:\Users\(me)\Downloads\`. Do I need to move it somewhere else?

Comment: You most likely need to add it as an environment variable - try [this](https://www.configserverfirewall.com/windows-10/add-python-to-path-windows-10/)

Comment: Um. What exactly do you mean by "in" your downloads directory. Just one file you downloaded sitting there? Or did you actually run the installer after downloading it, and tell it that the downloads directory is where you wanted it to install to?

Comment: Did you just download it, or did you actually install it, by running the installer?

Comment: ..._if_ you ran the installer, it should have updated your environment variables to have the new location be in the PATH.

Comment: when you install it, click the `add PYTHON to path` checkbox...  it is easy to miss and i don't know why it is not automatically checked.  hope that helps.

Comment: I downloaded "Windows installer (64-bit)" of Python 3.10.6 on the Python website.

Comment: @D.L, it isn't automatically checked, because it never needs to be added.

Comment: @Compo,   interesting.  So what is the purpose of the checkbox in that respect ?

Comment: Because @D.L, people are not taught to script properly, they and the tutorials they use have become lazy. The `%Path%` variable is essentially being used to dump paths so that lazy scripters or users of the CLI do not need to do some basic typing, or think about the environment the are working in. We all like to save a little bit of typing, but unfortunately, in this case the understanding of the environment suffers. What exactly do you think happens, when you `[ENTER]` the string `python`, as used in the question, at the Command Prompt?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've reinstalled it and checked the "add as environment variable" box in the installation wizard. Now it seems like the issue's fixed. Thanks, tcotts and Charles Duffy!